# using a local dynamic library on an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, dylib, dlopen

I have a dylib file on my macbook, and I want to use it in an iPhone application I create. I try using `dlopen` as usual:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
char* dylibPath = "/Users/benams/lib.dylib";    
void* libHandle = dlopen(dylibPath, RTLD_NOW);
```

`libHandle` is null and I guess the reason is that the dylib file doesn't exist on my iPhone. How can I solve it and use this dylib when I debug my app?

Comment: Is the dylib build for ARM?

Comment: @rckoenes yes, it's arm64

Answer (score 0):

In general you can open dynamic libraries on iOS, too. But you can't use a dynamic library for macOS on iOS, because they have different processor architectures (x86_64 vs. arm?). You have to compile your library for arm32 and arm64 processors. If you want deploy your app (in the app store), you must also code sign they library.

But it is much easier to create and include a static library for iOS, or use use a shared framework. Note: In general dynamic libraries or shared frameworks will only make sense when reused for multiple executables (e. g. app and its extensions).

Comment: it was built for IOS, `lipo -info` result: "Non-fat file: lib.dylib is architecture: arm64"

Comment: Do you have consulted `dlerror()` to get details about the error?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The error is: "dlopen(/Users/benams/lib.dylib, 2): image not found". As I stated above - the .dylib file is stored on my macbook, but I debug the application on my iPhone (means the file is not on the debugged machine)

Comment: You have to include the dynamic library into your app bundle to get it on the device.